# Align vertices in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'd like to make a geometry nodes setup that allows me to align a set of vertices between two points. I'd like to avoid using a curve or mesh line starting from a point and ending to another since I want the node setup to work with 4.0 node tools. I've been trying for quite some time now and can't figure out anything convincing. Any help is appreciated, thank you[image]

Comment: I haven't done a lot with 4.0 so far, pardon my stupid question: curve or mesh lines are not working in 4.0?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann They do work in 4.0, however this is not helpful when making a node tool which purpose is to deform or move the selected geometry since it wont be able to replace it (when there are faces connected to that selection for example). There could be a way to use them with geometry proximity but this is very sketchy and wont work very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exaclty what I was looking for, thank you. Now I'm going to try to space the points evenly. Thanks again